# Displaying Result and Expected values of an Assertion in CakePHP testing

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, netbeans, phpunit, assertion

Does anyone know if there is a way to force CakePHP TestSuite to view the Expected and Result values of an assertion when it fails? Typical PHPUnit tests are showing it by default in the output but not Cake's TestSuite (which uses PHPUnit). A side from that, when i debug a test case in NetBeans i get some kind of Socket Exception whenever i try to set a watch for a variable, and it only happens in CakePHP test cases, it works fine in evry other source file. Is there a solution for this aswell?

Answer (score 0):

check out
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/04/unit-testing-tips-for-2-0-and-phpunit/

basically, you can extend the TestCase class and make your own additional methods like

```
public function details($is, $expected) {
    echo 'is:' . $is; echo '<br />';
    echo 'expected: ' . $expected; ob_flush();
```

}

and call it internally or sth on fail.

or you just debug() everywhere.

Comment: Unfortunetely in my case when I try to echo anything from the TestCase it doesn't show up in the browser at all, plus it looks kinda hacky.

Comment: did you notice the "ob_flush"? you also need to output prior to the assert (on fail it will break immediately)

Comment: ah yes i missed the flush thing sorry, anyway i managed to work it the way i saw it big tnx anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I somehow worked it out tho the solution will be wiped when u update the Cake Library files. You need to edit the file `lib\Cake\TestSuite\Reporter\CakeHtmlReporter` and change the method:

```
public function paintFail($message, $test) 
{
    $trace = $this->_getStackTrace($message);
    $testName = get_class($test) . '(' . $test->getName() . ')';
    echo "<li class='fail'>\n";
    echo "<span>Failed</span>";
    echo "<div class='msg'><pre>" . $this->_htmlEntities($message) . "</pre></div>\n";
    echo "<div class='msg'>" . __d('cake_dev', 'Test case: %s', $testName) . "</div>\n";
    echo "<div class='msg'>" . __d('cake_dev', 'Stack trace:') . '<br />' . $trace . "</div>\n";
    echo "</li>\n";
}
```

to:

```
public function paintFail($message, $test) {
    $trace = $this->_getStackTrace($message);
    $testName = get_class($test) . '(' . $test->getName() . ')';

    echo "<li class='fail'>\n";
    echo "<span>Failed</span>";
    echo "<div class='msg'><pre>" . $this->_htmlEntities($message->getComparisonFailure()->toString()) . "</pre></div>\n";
    echo "<div class='msg'>" . __d('cake_dev', 'Test case: %s', $testName) . "</div>\n";
    echo "<div class='msg'>" . __d('cake_dev', 'Stack trace:') . '<br />' . $trace . "</div>\n";
    echo "</li>\n";
}
```

And this will output you something like this when the assertion fails:

```
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
-    0 => 'Crypto3DS'
-    1 => 'Zlib'
+    1 => 'Crypto3DS'
+    2 => 'Zlib'
 )
```

Faster testing in Cake Yeppie :D